# xsl:if evaluation with nmap output

Tags: xslt, nmap

For reference I am using Nmap 7.8, and I am attempting to format the output using an xsl file. Within the xsl file I call a second rules.xml file to do comparisons and add supplemental information. This is the structure of rules.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Item id="1">
        <info>Rule Information</info>
        <port>123</port>
        <port>321</port>
    </Item>
</root>
```

When I attempt to print the output of an nmap port with `<xsl:value-of select="@portid"/>` it works, however if I do an if, or choose/when operation it fails. When I do a static comparison `<xsl:if test="port = 321">` it works with either port value.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="ports/port">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="state/@state = 'open'">
            <xsl:variable name="rules" select="document('rules.xml')"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$rules/root/Item">
                <xsl:if test="port = @portid">                                      
                    <xsl:value-of select="info"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>                              
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The desired behavior is to loop through all ports within the nmap output and add the additional info tags in an Item which contains a matching port tag. The mapping is 1 Item to Many ports, so I would like to avoid indexing rules.xml with ports at the top level to prevent duplicate .

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ports/port">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="state/@state = 'open'">
            <xsl:variable name="portid" select="@portid"/>
            <xsl:variable name="rules" select="document('rules.xml')"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$rules/root/Item">
                <xsl:if test="port = $portid">                                      
                    <xsl:value-of select="info"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>                              
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or perhaps more succinctly:

```
<xsl:variable name="rules" select="document('rules.xml')"/>
<xsl:for-each select="ports/port[state/@state = 'open']">
    <xsl:variable name="portid" select="@portid"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$rules/root/Item[port = $portid]">
        <xsl:value-of select="info"/>
    </xsl:for-each>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

What you have now is looking for `Item` that has a child `port` whose value is equal to the value of the `portid` attribute **of the parent `Item`**.

Answer (score 1):

When using expressions like `port = @portId` you need to think about what the context item is. There's no element that has both a child `port` and an attribute `portId`, so it looks like the two sides of this expression are expecting different context items, which of course can't happen.

Generally when you're doing joins between several documents (or within a single document) you need to bind variables to nodes so that you can make explicit selections rather than relying on implicit context.